# How to verify that services are being used by a customer

Tags: data, data-collection, verification, geolocation, push-notification

I have a project, which is sending surveys to customers as soon as they use certain services like restaurants, beauty salons,...so how can these customers verify that they actually used this service?

I am thinking of sending a push notification with the link for the survey as soon as they entered the location of the service, but practically it sounds difficult.
Does anyone have experience performing this type of verification?

Comment: Do you research about if the customers want to take a survey about a service without tried or used that service?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56528)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the date of origin of records from the database may be suggestive 
The newer the entry - the higher the likelihood of it being up to date.There may also be an entry indicating the frequency of use of the services or whether in general someone has used them.

Often people sign up without being consumers at the same time, it is worth determining the value of this factor

Sending emails, in addition to offering reward payments, can also be a way

**You thought about qualitative research?**

It will give you initial insight and analysis of topics that You can then confirm quantitatively

Answer (score 0):

We have send surveys about quality of the service after the user has left the location of the service. Service being a restaurant. We have an application that contains for example restaurant menus and news about the restaurants.

We have used Bluetooth beacons to verify users' location through the method called [geofencing](https://www.cio.com/article/2383123/geofencing-explained.html). It has drawbacks though.

Users need to have Bluetooth enabled for geofencing to work. Application can force Bluetooth to be enabled for the application to work but this can put off some users.

Google and Apple also have started being quite aggressive about applications running in the background and about other devices scanning users' location which affects this kind of methods. Users have also started to be more wary about someone knowing their location.